# Get all sub classes of a class PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, reflection

I am looking to find all classes that extend MyParentClass, so I can run a specific static function on them.

I know php has a function get_declared_classes and i could then use `instanceof` or `Reflection::isSubclassOf()` but but my project has far too many classes for this to be used sensibly.

My next option is to make sure all the appropriate classes are in a specific folder then double check with Relection

Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Any reason to not just check if the class instance is a subclass instead of doing that?

Comment: this is why people starts using namespaces. Btw. you can use `instanceof` keyword

Comment: Note: my project has far too many classes to use get_declared_classes - I am looking to find all the child classes - I don't know what they are before hand

Comment: If what you're looking for exists, my guess is that it would use something very much like `get_declared_classes` under the hood, anyway. If your class *really* has too many classes to use `get_declared_classes` (meaning you've benchmarked that method and it has unacceptable performance), you might work around that by caching and/or pre-computing the list.

Answer (score 2):

You want to know which classes of your whole codebase extend a certain main class. This cannot be known without searching ALL your files for class definitions, then check all found classes whether or not they extend the main class (or extend a class that extends the main class...). `get_declared_classes()` will not help you because this function will only list classes that got used during the code execution before calling this function. It will not list any classes that are defined in a file, but not yet (auto)loaded.

I wonder what you are up to. You say you want to apply a static function on them - what is this exactly? I sense another instance of the [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. because you think that searching for all extending classes will solve your problem you are asking that, but instead you should be asking about the problem that made you think so.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sven answer.

Except the fact it might X-Y problem - there is another solution which comes to my mind:

You can create and maintain the class map.

```
$classes = array(
 'ClassA',
 'ClassB',
 // '...' 
);
```

Comment: A classmap is implicitly included in my answer. :) If you create it by hand, it will contain errors. When you create it automatically, it is essentially "scanning the whole codebase for classes".